# How to share a variable between classes without extensions

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

In a game I am working on, one class has the job of drawing a sprite while another class has the job of manipulating the coordinates (i.e if the sprite is about to go off of the screen, stop it there. Yes, I know this is vector graphics). Anyway, I need the coordinates to be shared between both classes. I have tried doing this with a class extension, but that generated a stack overflow because the superclass (the class that's drawing the sprite) has to make an instance of the subclass (the class that is going to manipulate the variables).

```
// In the superclass Render
public AnimateMC mc = new AnimateMC( 2 ); // AnimateMC is the subclass of the 
                                             superclass, Render
//later in the program
//code for drawing all of the shapes in the sprite
mc.gravitizeY(); // this is why I need to make an instance of AnimateMC

// In the subclass AnimateMC
// animates sprite by changing the coordinates
```

How would I be able to share the integer-variable coordinates between the two classes without extending one class.

Comment: What's wrong with getters and setters?  It's not totally clear from your example, but you're almost certainly overthinking this problem - it's a very common one.  Could you post a more detailed example?

Comment: I haven't covered getters and setters. I'm still a high-school student. What are those?

Comment: Pretty simple idea, one object (not class, be careful, the term you use is important) holds the coordinates, and has a `getCoordinates()` method which can be called and passed to the second object.

Answer (score 4):

You've learned that misuse of inheritance will not solve this problem. Instead extend through composition: Pass a reference to the sprite from one object to the other and work with the reference.

So give the class that needs to have access to the sprite a Sprite variable, sprite, and then pass in the Sprite reference via a setter method, i.e.,

```
public void setSprite(Sprite sprite) {
   this.sprite = sprite;
}
```

or set it through the class's constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fundamental [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) question, and my guess would be that you're missing the "Controller" part of it.  You need a central class who's job it is to manage both the game logic (Model) and display logic (View) and share data between them.  There's lots of resources out there, the Wikipedia article I linked to is a good start.

From the way you phrased your question, I suspect that you don't have a strong grasp on object inheritance yet - that's ok, it's not totally simple - but you almost never want to extend an object in order to share data between two different classes, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do here.

The general rule of thumb for "Should I extend this object?" is the [Has-A vs. Is-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship.  Basically, if an object Is-A other object, one likely should extend the other.  If not, they shouldn't.  Think `Car Is-A Vehicle` so `Car extends Vehicle` but `Car Has-A Sunroof` so `Sunroof` shouldn't extend `Car`.  Again, read the link for more.